# Confused about proof of Leibniz Integral Rule

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

If we set $G(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(x,y) dy$, then

\begin{align}
\frac{G(x+d)-G(x)}d =& \frac{\int_{0}^{x+d} f(x+d,y)dy - \int_{0}^{x} f(x,y)dy}d \\
=& \frac{\int_{0}^{x}f(x+d,y)dy+\int_{x}^{x+d} - \int_{0}^{x}f(x,y)dy}d
\end{align}

By grouping, $$\int_{0}^{x}\frac{f(x+d,y)-f(x,y)}ddy + \int_{x}^{x+d}f(x+d,y)dy,$$ which leads to:

$$\int_{0}^{x}f'(x,y)dy + \frac{\int_{0}^{x+d}f(x+d,y)dy-\int_{0}^{x}f(x+d,y)dy}d.$$

Why is the second term not equal to $f(x+d,x)$? I know it isn't, I'm just trying to see where I'm going wrong in the proof.

Comment: Nice 1st question!

Comment: Why do you think that the term (after the limit $d\to0$) should not be equal to $f(x,x)$?

Comment: Are you assuming that $f$ is continuous on a compact set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main sticking point is understanding why 
$$\lim_{d\to 0}\frac{\int_{x}^{x+d}f(x+d,y)dy}{d}=f(x,x).$$
To prove this note that 
$$d\inf_{y\in[x,x+d]} f(x+d,y)\leq\int_{x}^{x+d}f(x+d,y)dy\leq d\sup_{y\in[x,x+d]} f(x+d,y),$$
assuming that $f$ is continuous on a compact set. Now simply divide through by $d$ and then take the limit as $d\to 0$. The squeeze theorem does the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the limit $d\to0$, the second term **is** equal to $f(x,x)$. In fact you have shown that $$\frac{d}{dx} G(x)= \int_0^x f_x(x,y)dy + f(x,x).$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\frac{\int_{0}^{x+d}f(x+d,y)dy-\int_{0}^{x}f(x+d,y)\,dy}d=
\frac{\int_{x}^{x+d}f(x+d,y)\,dy}d=
\frac{\int_{0}^{d}f(x+d,x+u)\,du}d$$

Now, if $f$ is continuous and $d\to 0$, what can you say about the expression above?